# IIS Logging of HTTP Header Fields

Tags: iis, iis-10

How can I log request header fields with IIS. There is the possibility to add custom logging fields, but I want to log the value of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`, which is not listed in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

I have used only IIS 2016 and do not know what is your version.
Have to tried to choose X-Forwarded-For Header which is standard header for identifying HTTP and HTTPS.
There are a few example [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-use-x-forwarded-for-header-to-log-actual-client-ip/ba-p/873115) and [here](https://support.kemptechnologies.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002861712-How-to-Add-an-X-Forwarded-For-Header-and-Configuring-IIS-Logging)

Comment: I found now a solution, where I can view all server variables. The HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is the same value for all requests, because I'm behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution. I can debug all server variables of IIS with such a simple site on the webserver. So I don't have to use the log.

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables)
{
  Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>");
}
%>
```